# What does the term "OS running mapped/unmapped" mean?

Tags: operating-system

I'm currently taking an OS course.

The notes said:

*In some cases the OS just runs unmapped. Then all it has to do is read the tables and translate user addresses in software. However, addresses that are contiguous in the virtual address space may not be contiguous physically. Thus I/O operations may have to be split up into multiple blocks.*

*Suppose the OS also runs mapped, then it must generate a page table entry for the user area. Note that under no circumstances should users be given access to mapping tables.*

I have three questions:

- What does OS running unmapped mean?
- What about the definition of OS running mapped?
- Why do I/O operations may have to be split up into multiple blocks when OS is running unmapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough context to be 100% sure; but I suspect that:

a) When they say "OS" they actually mean "kernel". Note that an OS is a huge thing consisting of many pieces (help system, files for internationalization, GUI, various libraries, various utilities for managing the system, etc) where almost all of an OS (everything except the kernel) is normal user-space stuff.

b) "OS just runs unmapped" actually means that kernel runs with MMU disabled (so that kernel has direct access to physical memory with no "translation of virtual addresses into physical addresses" involved). For real hardware this is horrible (CPUs cache the "virtual address to physical address" translations in something called a TLB/translation look-aside buffer, and disabling the MMU when entering the kernel and re-enabling it when returning from the kernel causes TLBs to be flushed, which ruins performance due to "TLB misses").

c) "OS also runs mapped" actually means that kernel runs with MMU enabled (so that kernel has to ensure stuff is mapped into the virtual address space to access it, because it doesn't have direct access to physical memory). Note that the kernel may just map some/most/all of physical memory into all virtual address spaces so that it always has "almost direct" access to physical memory.

> Why do I/O operations may have to be split up into multiple blocks when OS is running unmapped?

If user-space is using MMU (to translate virtual addresses into physical addresses) and "contiguous in virtual memory" doesn't mean "contiguous in physical memory"; IO to/from user-space (e.g. `read()`, `write()`) would have to be split into "physically contiguous" pieces for devices. In this case it makes no difference if kernel is/isn't mapped (or is/isn't using MMU) - it only matters that user-space is using MMU.

If kernel is also using MMU and "contiguous in virtual memory" doesn't mean "contiguous in physical memory" for kernel-space; IO to/from kernel would also have to be split into "physically contiguous" pieces for devices.